# Summing values in the first column based on the rest of the line with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file which has several duplicating lines that only differ in the first column.

Original file:

```
2 A 3 rr 44 5 t y uuu 8
3 A 3 rr 44 5 t y uuu 8
0 B f 1
1 C 6 5 55 yy 7 4 3 4-5 tt efvho 44 3 5 gg 5  4 t rr 33
5 C 6 5 55 yy 7 4 3 4-5 tt efvho 44 3 5 gg 5  4 t rr 33
5 C 6 5 55 yy 7 4 3 4-5 tt efvho 44 3 5 gg 5  4 t rr 33
3 D tt v 44 f1 p
1 D tt v 44 f1 p
```

What I would like is to get rid of the duplicates and sum the values from column 1.

Desired output:

```
5 A 3 rr 44 5 t y uuu 8
0 B f 1
11 C 6 5 55 yy 7 4 3 4-5 tt efvho 44 3 5 gg 5  4 t rr 33
4 D tt v 44 f1 p
```

This script is quite close to what I want to do:

```
awk  '{a[$2]+=$1}END{for(i in a)print a[i] , i |"sort"}' file
```

Giving this output:

```
5 A 
0 B 
11 C 
4 D
```

Is there a way to change $2 to all columns but the first in this script?

Comment: do we need to keep the order of lines?

Comment: No, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, but won't keep the order of lines:

```bash
awk '{v=$1; $1=""; s[$0]=s[$0]+v} END {for (r in s) { printf "%s%s\n",s[r],r }}' file
```

- save first field in a variable, then empty it.
- save an array with the row (with emptied `$1`) as key and the sum up the saved `$1` as its value.
- in the end, print the array. I use `printf` to avoid the extra space that comes, because we cannot delete, but only empty `$1`.

add `| sort -k2` to sort on the second column.

Output:

```
5 A 3 rr 44 5 t y uuu 8
0 B f 1
11 C 6 5 55 yy 7 4 3 4-5 tt efvho 44 3 5 gg 5 4 t rr 33
4 D tt v 44 f1 p
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `datamash` and `awk`:

Because duplicating lines differ in first column only, this `datamash` command would work.

```bash
$ datamash -s -t' ' groupby 2 sum 1 --full <file | 
awk '{$1=$NF; NF -= 1}1'
```

Comment: Decrementing NF is undefined behavior per POSIX so different awk versions will do different things with that.

Answer (score 0):

Only storing 1 line at a time in memory and reproducing the input order in the output using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    currKey = $0
    sub(/[^[:space:]]+ /,"",currKey)
}
currKey != prevKey {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        print prev0
    }
    prevKey = currKey
    prev1 = 0
}
{
    $1 += prev1
    prev1 = $1
    prev0 = $0
}
END {
    print prev0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
5 A 3 rr 44 5 t y uuu 8
0 B f 1
11 C 6 5 55 yy 7 4 3 4-5 tt efvho 44 3 5 gg 5 4 t rr 33
4 D tt v 44 f1 p
```

The above assumes your duplicate lines are grouped together. If not just run `sort -k2 file | awk '...'`.